# Python apps in the Mac app store with TKinter

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter, mac-app-store

I have written a game in Tkinter GUI in python. I am able to package the game into an app with py2app. Is it possible to deploy the executable to the mac app store? Do I need to use a different GUI builder? I am using Tkinter because it is default on all macs... 
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure on Tkinter apps but Kivy: http://kivy.org/#home is a cross platform framework

Comment: I don't want to use another GUI builder... I need to stick with Tkinter.

Comment: if you google "py2app in ios store", the first result is related to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use py2app or, as I do, cx_Freeze to deploy a Tkinter app to the Mac App Store. See https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickwho/id419483981?mt=12 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this operability is high, because one of my small Python programs based on Tkinter's 200 lines of code was rejected for the following reasons:

```
Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

• Contents/Frameworks/libtk8.6.dylib/NSDrawerWindow

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
```